# Splitting a Java String

Tags: java, string, date

I have a `YYYYMM` date in `String` format. I want to split it into `YYYY` and `MM` and replace the existing `YYYY` with a new year and concatenate it back in Java.

For example, I have `201201`. I want to split it into `2012` and `01` and change `2012` to `2000` and finally get `200001`. How do I do it?

I googled it but everyone seemed to have a `-` or a `*` in between.

Or if anyone knows a better way to do it (maybe change it into a `Date` and modify the year), I am all ears.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Change `"YYYYMM"` to `"YYYY MM"`

Comment: Substring, change, concat.

Comment: I cannot change it. I am getting the value from a csv file.

Comment: `string.substring(0,2)+"00"+string.substring(4);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to this code to see if it can help you.

```
 String myDate = "201201";
  String myDate1 = myDate.substring(0, 4);
  String myDate2 = myDate.substring(4);
  myDate1 = "2000"; //Change the logic accordingly with your spec
  System.out.println(myDate1 + myDate2);
```

Answer (score 1):

One uber-simple approach is just to use string manipulation:

```
String orig = "201201";
String changed = "2000" + orig.substring(4);
```

**EDIT:**
A looping example, as per the comment:

```
// Loop over the inputs
for (String date : getDatesFromFile() {
    // Loop over 10 years:
    for (int year = 2000; year <= 2010; ++year) {
        String newDate = String.valueOf(year) + date.substring(4);

        // write newDate to an output file
    }
}
```

Comment: 2000 was an example. I have to put it in a loop and do it for 10 years. Get the value from a csv file, modify it for the current year in the loop and write to a new file.

Comment: @CleanSock The same principle should still apply - see my edit.

Comment: Thanks Mureinik! I got the idea on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

try This :

```
  String Str = new String("201201");
  System.out.print("Replace Year :" );
  System.out.println(Str.replace('2012', '2000'));
```